# WPF c# mailItem htmlbody not editable

Tags: c#, html, wpf, outlook, mailitem

Is there anyway to make a mailItem body not editable?

I mean, I have the mail item and I populate it with a html body, I have to display it to user input to, cc, etc. but I dont want him to change the body.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. And item in the sent state will not be editable. See [Why are MailItems created in Sent Items folder shown in compose mode in Outlook 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898396/why-are-mailitems-created-in-sent-items-folder-shown-in-compose-mode-in-outlook) for a discussion on how to create items in the sent state.